# A node with massive degree in graph brings taking distinct() edges trouble

Tags: mapreduce, graph-theory, apache-flink

I have a graph that around 75% connectivity comes from only one node

e.g. if the sum of degree of all nodes is 100, this node's degree is 75.

After some manipulations, 
massive duplicate edges exist regarding this node.

Assume 1 is this kind of node

1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,3
1,3
1,3

However, it has too many duplicate keys for taking distinct() edges. 
I have tried re-partition before taking distinct() but it still doesn't work out of too many duplicate keys, and now writing into disk and then taking distinct() solves this problem.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of extremely skew problem?

Comment: High-degree nodes can be a pain in graph processing and significantly slow down vertex-parallel computations. A solution that has been proposed is to try and parallelize over the edges instead. However, it seems to me that your problem is a bit different. I understand you have a highly skewed node, but your issue is that you end up having too many duplicate edges.
What kind of manipulations end up producing so many duplicate edges? Is there a way to reduce the duplicate edge generation earlier?
Is distinct() giving you an error and if yes, could you post it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying that makes me understand the problem better. Distinct() gives an error about too many duplicate keys. Current solution is I write the edges into disk and then read them from disk and take distinct(). The manipulation is a node in the edge joins with the other data, so high degree node has lots lots of duplicate edges.

Comment: I haven't seen this error ("too many duplicate keys") in a distinct() before. Might it be the case that the error is coming from the join and not from the distinct? In that case, I believe [this discussion thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Hash-join-failing-td1389.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Yes that also happened before in my code and have already applied that technique.

Comment: What kind of code is causing the issue? Is it occurring in the "Gelly" library, or is the problem occurring as part of a Java/Scala API distinct? If you call the "distinct()" before the join, does it work?